# How to prevent KDE from loading the Gnome desktop for fullscreen applications?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, 64-bit, kde, fullscreen

Every time I start an application that is using fullscreen mode in KDE my gnome desktop background is loaded before starting the program. This is aesthetically diturbing and I suspect there is a waste of ressources when the gnome system is somehow started in the background.

Affected are:

- wine applications using fullscreen (started via playonlinux)
- virtualbox using fullscreen or scaled modus
- firefox flash plugin

What I did (inspired by some hints in various forums): 
replaced gdm with lightdm (flash plugin seems to be fixed now) 
used "killall nautilus" - but this had no effect at all.

How can I make sure KDE doesn't use any gnome programs or settings in the background without removing gnome (as gnome is used as an alternative login for testing purposes!)?

p.s.: I am using 11.04 Ubuntu with kubuntu desktop installed, 64bit, newest nvidia drivers

Here's the output of "ps aex | tee" as suggested: http://paste.ubuntu.com/678832/

Comment: Hmmm...never heard of t9his happening before. Does it also happen when you use gdm? Could you also post the output of `ps aex | tee`? That will output a list of running commands.

Comment: Yes it happens with gdm. The requested output is really long, how to post it here?

Comment: use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and add a link into your question.

Comment: hithere! sry for being absent for a while. Here's a link to the paste.ubuntu.com: http://paste.ubuntu.com/678832/ . thx. But it's only about 10% of the output. semms to be cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost without a doubt I can be sure you are running Dropbox, which starts Nautilus under KDE no matter what you do. If you want nautilus to go away, you can run `killall -9 nautilus`. You can even add this to KDE startup applications and have it run only in KDE.

Comment: I stopped dropbox and the issue seems to be better now. But I have to test a bit before being sure. SO is there a way to run dropbox for KDE with Dolphin being the filebrowser?

Comment: @piedro there is (was) an application called kfilebox or something, but it doesn't work anymore, and the site seems to be down.

Comment: thx roland, I use kfilebox, it's still working for me, but it loads "nautilus-dropbox" indeed! There seems to be a file browser independent dropbox daemon, but i couldn't find a deb file for it nor a comprehensive installation guide.

Comment: @piedro: yeah sucks for KDE users :(. It's one of the reasons I don't use KDE more. BTW you should mark this as answering your question.

Comment: Hallo Roland! sry for me being absent for a while. It doesn't work. Even after killing everything related to dropbox, still the problem remains. I think I have to ask a more general question how to truely separate the gnome and KDE side of things on the same computer.